# Target the current value of an option list using js, and add that value to an object?

Tags: dom, javascript-objects

HTML

```html
<div class="options-container">
 <select id="all-options">
  <option value="0" selected>NY</option>
  <option value="1">LA</option>
  <option value="2">Toronto</option>
  <option value="3">Paris</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

JS

```js
let selectedOption = {};
let allOptions = document.getElementById('all-options');
let optionValue = allOptions.options[all-options.selectedIndex].value;
if (optionValue == "0") {
    selectedOption.value === "0"
} else if (optionValue  === "1") {
    selectedOption.value === "1"
} else if (optionValue  === "2") {
    selectedOption.value === "2"
} else if (optionValue  === "3") {
    selectedOption.value === "3"
};
```

I'm attempting to target the current value of an option list element in my HTML file using JS so that I can add that value to the selectedOption object. The value can be added either as a string or number object.

Comment: Your question is unclear - what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have a drop-down menu and want to arrange my JS so that if I select LA, I want the value of "1" to be pushed to the object selectedOption, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Defining the Event Listener

You're going to want to define an event listener in your `<select>`. For example:

```js
        function onSelectItem(evt)
        {
            let value = evt.target.selectedOptions[0].value;
            let text = evt.target.selectedOptions[0].text;

            // Assign it how you want here:
            selectedOption = value;
        }
```

You can't really "push" to an object. If you meant an array, change the selected option to an array (`[]`) and do `selectedOption.push(value)`. If you want a useful object, however, you could just assign it to `evt.target.selectedOptions[0]`.

#### Attaching the Listener

After that, you can attach it in html, and pass the event object via the default `event` variable:

```html
    <select id="all-options" onchange="onSelectItem(event)">
      <option value="0">NY</option>
      <option value="1">LA</option>
      <option value="2">Toronto</option>
      <option value="3">Paris</option>
    </select>
```

or more Javascript when the page loads (by setting the `onload` attribute to `"init()"` in `<body>`):

```js
        function init()
        {
            let menu = document.getElementById('all-options');

            menu.addEventListener('change', onSelectItem);
            // Since it seems that you also want a default selected value when the 
            // page loads, you should probably also initialize your `selectedOption` to `0`.
            selectedOption = menu.selectedOptions[0].value;
        }
```